# How to create a Turing machine that takes a single digit decimal number from 0 - 9 and output the cube

Tags: turing-machines

I'm working on a project for a Turning machine but having problems conceptualizing the steps.

```
f(x) = x^3, where x is a single digit between 0 - 9 inclusive.
```

Based on my understanding I am to convert the number to binary but how do I find the cube of a number in binary.

Also, how do I write the cube on the tape.

So far I'm thinking I should create a state diagram that accepts the binary versions of 0-9 but what next?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder about the "single digit" - could it be that this Turing machine can write the symbols 0-9 (plus blank)? That would make this a lot more doable. In binary (or, worse, unary) it's a ton of pointless busywork.

Comment: That was my exact approach originally but when I took the design to the tutor she said the turing machine can only deal with binary. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

- Write a copy of the number to the left of your current number
- Write another copy to the left of that
- Multiply the original number with the first copy, erasing the copy
- Multiply the result by the second copy, erasing that

You will need to write a copy and a multiply "subroutine" (using states) and jump into those by setting the right states. But I think this should be doable (if a lot of work). But probably less work than encoding all cubes from 0 to 9.

Comment: How do I go about writing a copy? As far as I know the transition for a turing machine is usually in the form {0, 1 -> R} {where you read in a digit, replace it with something else and move on.} Can I write two digits, e.g. {0, 11 -> R}?

Comment: No. I think you would need to read the digit, remember it in the state, find the end of the copy, and append it.